# How can I determine if a `git` branch is a remote-tracking branch using Magit?

Tags: magit, git

Is there a function `magit-magic` such that

```
(magit-magic "master") => t
(magit-magic "origin/master") => nil
```

assuming `origin/master` is a fetched, but possibly unpulled branch on remote `origin`? (Sorry, I don't know the proper git terminology -- which is probably why I'm having trouble finding an answer on my own.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Remote-tracking branch" is the official terminology, but Magit doesn't follow it strictly in this case.  The function is called `magit-remote-branch-p`. (Well it does the opposite of what your `magit-matic` does).